# minimax with alpha beta pruning and write search tree to disk

Tags: c++, artificial-intelligence

I am using minimax algorithm with alpha beta pruning for an AI project. When the opponent human player is thinking, the AI wants to continue generating possible moves. But as the move depth increases ( say beyond 7-8), the system consumes too much memory space. Is it advisable to store the search tree on disk or is there any other possible way out?

Comment: (1) It surprises me, that you seem to reach some memory-limit that fast. Is your implementation correct (and using iterative deepening)? (2) The basic concept of yours usually is called **pondering** if i recall correctly. (3) It's not advisable as IO is way too slow to help here.

Comment: The board is not as complicate as chess but not as simple as tic-tac-toe. The number of the branches inspite of alpha - beta prunning runs into 32 millions. Thing are fine if the depth level is less than 5, but the decision making is poorer.

Comment: Usually you don't store the tree, just the position at each level as you go along, and the best result you've seen so far.